# jQuery slider fade effect without white areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fade, effect

Heyo,

I'm currently working on a background slider but I can't make it work as I want it to work.

So what I need is a fade-effect which produces no white space between the images.

So ... the following image should `fadeIn` but the current image should just stay and `fadeOut` when the `fadeIn` effect of the following image is done. (If that makes sense)

This is the current `script` I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = 1;
  var images = [ "http://i.imgur.com/HX0X6lV.png", "http://i.imgur.com/N50Ye7i.png", "http://i.imgur.com/TFG5oaa.png"];
  var image = $(".background");

  setInterval(function(){
   image.fadeOut(500, function(){
    image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");
    image.fadeIn(500);
   });
   if(count == images.length)
   {
    count = 0;
   }
  },3000);

});
```

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/HX0X6lV.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>
```